# How to get element without removing the item in python asyncio.Queue()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

The `asyncio.Queue` `get()` method will remove and return an item from the queue.

But I just want to read the item, not remove it. How do I do that?

```
queue = asyncio.Queue()
result = await queue.get()
```

Here I just want to know the value of the result, but do not want to remove that from the queue.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. Cant you just save the results into a list for later use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this although it's a bit of a hack and potentially won't work in all Python versions. It does work in 3.9.6 although it's probably not thread-safe:-

```
import queue

TQ = queue.Queue()

TQ.put(99)
TQ.put(100)

for q in TQ.__dict__['queue']:
    print(q)
```

This will emit the values 99 & 100