# Access all elements in asyncio.Queue without removing them

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio, deque

I'm working on a program that uses a [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html).
It would be nice to be able to clear the queue, access all queued elements without removing them, and to insert elements at "index 1" in the queue.

I know, this sounds like a [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), but I rely on async/await code (i.e. [blocking get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.get)).

My approach:

- `clear`: Remove all elements from the queue until it's empty.
- `get_all`: Remove element, add to list, queue element again, repeat `qsize()` times. Return the list.
- `appendleft`: Queue element. Then remove and append `qsize() - 1` elements from/to queue until

```py
class BlockingDeque(asyncio.Queue):
    def clear(self):
        while not self.empty():
            self.get_nowait()
            self.task_done()

    def get_all(self):
        all = []
        for i in range(self.qsize()):
            item = self.get_nowait()
            self.task_done()
            self.put_nowait(item)
            all.append(item)
        return all

    async def appendleft(self, item):
        await self.put(item)
        for _ in range(self.qsize() - 1):
            item = self.get_nowait()
            self.task_done()
            self.put_nowait(item)
```

I also came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699144/7259176), which accesses `asyncio.Queue().__dict__['_queue']`.

```py
class BlockingDeque(asyncio.Queue):
    def clear(self):
        self._queue.clear()

    def get_all(self):
        return self._queue.copy()

    def appendleft(self, x):
        self._queue.appendleft(x)
```

Which approach is preferable? Is there a better way of doing it?